# Python forming a dictionary from a text file with value being a tuple

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
import pickle
def create_dict():



    final_image_dict = {}
    f_name = "./images/image_dict.txt"

    handle = open(f_name, encoding = 'utf-8')
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith(" ") : continue
        terms = line.split(": ")
        term = terms[0]
        dict_tuple = terms[1].split(",")
        caption = dict_tuple[0]
        image = dict_tuple[1]

        final_image_dict[term] = final_image_dict.get(term, dict_tuple)


    with open("./images/final_image_dict.txt", "wb") as image_infile:
        pickle.dump(final_image_dict, image_infile)
```

I am trying , with the above function, to create a dictionary in the format of key:(caption, image) from a text file of the following format:

```
addugliare:  (Coil a rope = Avvolgere a spire una cima,addugliare.gif),
admiral:  (classic anchor= ancora classico,admiral.gif),
aft:  (verso la poppa, aft.gif),
alberatura: (mastage,alberatura.gif),
albero: (mast = albero, albero.gif),
ancore: (anchors, anchore.gif),
andatu: (tacks, andatu.gif),
armi: (sailing craft, armi.gif),
bearing: (rilevamento , bearing.gif), etc
```

My problem is in creating the tuple for the value.
The above gives `{'mooring': [' (ormeggio', ' mooring.gif)', '\n'], 'knot(speed)': [' (nodo(velocità)', ' knot.gif)', '\n'], 'addugliare': [' (Coil a rope = Avvolgere a spire una cima', 'addugliare.gif)'`, rather than `'mooring': ('ormeggio','mooring.gif')` which is the format that I want. Could someone please help. I have also tried (caption, image) which seems to return a tuple of a tuple which doesn't work for me either

Comment: you must give the file `image_dict.txt` you are trying to read for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. Where I wrote 'from a text file in the following format' is extracted directly from image_dict.txt exactly in the format shown in my question ( without the etc)

Comment: Which makes me think, looking at it from your point of view, that the problem is probably with the parentheses that are in the text. Will remove them and try again. How stupid of me!!

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, still get a list [ ]rather than a tuple ()

Comment: OK Solved this issue by replacing 'final_image_dict[term] = final_image_dict.get(term, dict_tuple)' with final_image_dict[term] = final_image_dict.get(term, (caption, image))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this (modified to ignore blank lines and trailing whitespace):

```
def extractTuple(s):
    s = s.strip()
    n = len(s)
    p = s[1:n-1].split(',')
    return (p[0].strip(),p[1].strip())

def dictFromFile(fname):
    f = open(fname)
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    f.close()
    d = {}
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith(','):
            line = line[:len(line)-1]
            k,v = line.split(':')
            d[k] = extractTuple(v)
    return d
```

With your example data:

```
>>> d = dictFromFile("test.txt")
>>> for k in d: print(k,':',d[k])

admiral : ('classic anchor= ancora classico', 'admiral.gif')
armi : ('sailing craft', 'armi.gif')
addugliare : ('Coil a rope = Avvolgere a spire una cima', 'addugliare.gif')
aft : ('verso la poppa', 'aft.gif')
andatu : ('tacks', 'andatu.gif')
alberatura : ('mastage', 'alberatura.gif')
albero : ('mast = albero', 'albero.gif')
ancore : ('anchors', 'anchore.gif')
bearing : ('rilevamento', 'bearing.gif')
```